# How can I use selenium with docker?

Tags: python, selenium, docker, firefox

I'm expecting selenium to run after running a script with docker, at first I got the error

```
Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

So I tried installing firefox with 
`RUN apt-get install firefox` but I got the error

```
Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I have checked my log file and it is empty

Comment: I would recommend using the `StandaloneFirefox` image for Selenium so you don't have to worry about having everything installed with your docker file. Get more information [HERE](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

Comment: @PixelEinstein Heard your voice after a decade. How are things at your end?

Comment: @DebanjanB Things are good, started freelancing on the side and I'm really busy. How about you? Your score has gone way up! Nice.

Comment: @PixelEinstein Great news !!! Score is due to you and the community belief in my answers and solutions. Do keep visiting us.